# File paths must be fully qualified - Puppet

Tags: puppet

I have just started with puppet and I have an elementary question on using variables in a class. This is my class

```
# == Class: mysql::configure_mysql
class mysql::configure_mysql inherits mysql {

  $mysql_backup = "/var/mysql_backup"

  #Create directories 
  file { 'mysql_backup':
    path   => '($mysql_backup)',
    ensure => 'directory',
  }
}
```

I am getting an error

```
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter path failed on File[mysql_backup]: File paths must be fully qualified, not '($mysql_backup)'
```

Can someone please help me with how to declare a variable and use it?

I have used this for reference: https://serverfault.com/questions/41577/how-to-fix-puppet-fully-qualified-parameter-path-error

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`''` is a string literal in coding languages. You need the variable `$mysql_backup` to be resolved. Your resource was literally using the string `($mysql_backup)`. You also need to remove those parantheses as they are only a syntax error. For these reasons, `'($mysql_backup)'` needs to be changed to `$mysql_backup`. You could also put double quotes around the variable, but there would be no point to it.

```
file { 'mysql_backup':
  path    => $mysql_backup,
  ensure  => 'directory',
}
```

Puppet also uses the title of a file resource as the path, so you could shorten your resource to:

```
file { $mysql_backup: ensure => 'directory' }
```

Comment: Also can you please guide me where can i store global variables and how do i use them across different modules? I would really appreciate that.

Comment: @Adithya Global variables that can be used by Puppet would either be accessed from Facter (literal globals that would be defined by your system) or data (now Hiera, later Puppet Data Provider; these would be defined by you). Check out these links: https://docs.puppet.com/facter/ https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/.

Answer (score 0):

The file's title must be the absoloute path to your file.

```
 file { '/your/full/file/path/here':
    path    => "${mysql_backup}"
    ensure  => 'directory',
    }
```

Comment: Changing the title isn't necessary, but specifying the path in either the title _or_ the path parameter is. Fixing the quotes as you've done will do the latter.

Answer (score 0):

The path should be set with:

```
path => $mysql_backup,
```

The reason it didn't work in your case was that variables (like $mysql_backup) are not interpolated in single quotes. Changing the single quotes to double quotes would help, but then you would also need to remove the extraneous `(..)` brackets.